# ios UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate doesn't ignore opacity

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to dynamically change the color and opacity of the images given to me by the designer. Of course, it works seamlessly with the following code :

```
_imgViewForMenu.tintColor = [_lblForMenu.textColor colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0f];
// This alpha component wont affect the png image with 38% opacity. 
// You will never get full black image with [UIColor blackColor] 
// and alpha component 1.0

_imgViewForMenu.image = [imageForMenuIcon imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
```

This will work, but only when the image has no opacity of its own. Else as said in the comment for the code, it wont work.

So the question is, how do you render an image to ignore both its color component as well as opacity. The system controls like UITabBar and UIBarButonItem seem to do it with ease. Why not with UIImageView then?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
extension UIImage {
    func tinted(with color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        let image = withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, image.scale)
        color.set()
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
        let tintedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return tintedImage
    }
}
```